# PIC C Compiling Errors with PIC16F877A

Tags: c, controller, pic

I'm trying to compile the following code

```
#include <16f877a.h> //PIC SELECTION
#fuses hs, NOWDT, BROWNOUT,noPUT, NOLVP //FUSES CONFIGURATIONS
#use delay (clock=8000000) //4MHZ OSC
#INCLUDE <lcd.c> //INCLUDE LCD.C
#define use_portb_kbd TRUE //USE PORT B FOR KEYPAD
#INCLUDE <kbd.c> //include Keypad

unsigned char kbd_read()
{
    unsigned char C;
    C=kbd_getc();
    while(C==’\0′) {
        C=kbd_getc();
    }
}

void main()
{
    char c[4];
    kbd_init(); //KEYPAD INIT.
    lcd_init();

    lcd_putc(” WELCOME To \nKahrabje Coures”);
    delay_ms(3000);

    while(1)
    {
        start:
        lcd_putc(“\f type password\n”);
        c[0]=kbd_read();lcd_putc(‘*’);//if(c[0]!=’1′);lcd_putc(“\f faild”);
        delay_ms(1000);goto start;
        c[1]=kbd_read();lcd_putc(‘*’);
        c[2]=kbd_read();lcd_putc(‘*’);
        c[3]=kbd_read();lcd_putc(‘*’);

        if(c[0]==’1’&& c[1]==’2′ && c[2]==’3′ && c[3]==’4′){
            printf(lcd_putc,”\fwelcome”);
        }
        else {
            printf(lcd_putc,”\ffaild”);
        }

        delay_ms(1000);

    }
}
```

First I had Error 18(file can not be found), after a few attempts (using project wizard, making sure of file name.. etc) I ended up with Error 23 (Can not change device type this far into the code)

Any idea why I'm having these errors?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Aside: please note that the compiler will probably not like "smart quotes", better use 'single' and "double" quote style.

Comment: To rephrase @WeatherVane, Try `”` --> `"` and `’` --> `'`

Comment: It would really help to give the full text of the error message, including file, line number, etc and the version of the compiler in use.